# Pymongo using $exists

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to pymongo and having trouble using exists. When using

```py
collection.find({}, { "cwc": { "$exists": True }})
```

I get the following error

```
Unsupported projection option: $exists
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to find all `_id` and `cwc` where 'cwc' exists and not empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
collection.find({"$and":[ {"cwc":{"$exists": True}}, {"cwc":{"$ne": ""}}]})
```

Answer (score 21):

This works for me.

```py
collection.find({"cwc":{"$exists":True}})
```

The only difference is removed the first argument.