# PyMongo get to find json object based on field value

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I created a MongoDB with a collection like so:

```
{
    "FR" : {...},
    "EN": {...}
}
```

I'm pretty new with the world MongoDB/PyMongoDB so I was wondering if there is a way to get the data based on key (FR or EN) ?

I've tried this: `db.collection.find_one({'EN'})` but it did not work.

Cheers,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pymongo using $exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895213/pymongo-using-exists)

Comment: Not to sure of how to use the `$exists` keyword. but I have this expression:

`db.collection.find({'EN': {'$exists': True}})` and i obtain all the collection (FR and EN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` uses a `filter` and `projection` as the [first two parameters](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find). The filter determines which documents are returned and the projections determines which fields are returned.

So to get the data you are interested in use:

```
for doc in db.collection.find({}, {'EN': 1}):
    print(doc.get('EN'))
```

Comment: instead of using loop, I can directly use the index = 0 since the result of the item has only one value.:
for example: `db.collection.find({}, {'EN': 1})[0]`

Comment: The loop is there for the *records* not the *field* . If you know you want exactly one record, use `find_one()`